# Is there a reason why I cannot authenticate using passportjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport-local

I am writing a nodejs authentication moddule. I have followed all the instructions on the passportjs documentation and yet my application does not work. I am using a local instance of mongodb which running just fine.

I manually created the user on a local instance of mongodb. The user is in the users collection. I then used mongoose to connect to the database from my application. I was expecting that I will get an indication that the login was successful when using the local stragety. When the application is running I issue a curl from the terminal with user information. I can see that my application correctly receive the request but then I passportjs keeps on failing

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const bcrypt = require('password-hash-and-salt');


const app = express();
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    passpwod: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

app.use(session({
    secret: "verygoodsecrete",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());


//passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    })
})

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
    console.log('find user');
    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
        if(err) {return done(err)}
        if(!user) {return done (null, false, {message: 'Incorrect User.'})};
        return done(null, user);
    })
}))

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('We are on the landing page');
})

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/failedtologin'
}));

app.get('/failedtologin', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('failed to log in');
});

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('listening on port 4000')
})
```

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? Do you see the 'find user' log in console? If so, can you log username and password just to make sure they are correctly received?

Comment: Because I am using curl from the terminal, I get the following message: Found. Redirecting to /failedtologin. Which tells me that passport is unable to successfully authenticate. Now if I remove the passport middle-wear and just console.log the username like so (console.log(req,body.username)). I can see my username. Hope this provides clarity

Comment: I am sorry this is not helpful at all as you did not answer my first 2 questions. Also, are you certain of the curl you are executing? Could we see that too?

Comment: So I had some free time and copied your code. Everything works flawlessly when I cURL my way in. IF the username I pass exists in the database that is.

Comment: Here is my curl:curl -X POST localhost:4000/login -d '{"username": "mdu"}' -H "content-type: application/json"